# ReactJs / TypeError: demo.map is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i have a problem with my code, i use reactJs and redux.

my action my action my action my action :

```
// DEMO
export const demoFetchRequest = () => {
  return {
    type: DEMO_FETCH_REQUEST,
  };
};
export const demoFetchSuccess = (demo) => {
  return {
    type: DEMO_FETCH_SUCCESS,
    demo,
  };
};
export const demoFetchError = (error) => {
  return {
    type: DEMO_FETCH_ERROR,
    error,
  };
};
```

my reducer my reducer my reducer my reducer my reducer :

```
const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  demo: [],
  error: null,
};
const demo = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case DEMO_FETCH_REQUEST:
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case DEMO_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, loading: false, demo: action.demo };
    case DEMO_FETCH_ERROR:
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.error };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

my data my data my data my data my data my data my data :

```
const demoCompletedData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    marketId: "1111-1111-1111-1111",
    title: "Autonomous car",
    picture: "https://th?id=OIP.fdvfdvfdvfdvfd&pid=Api",
    language: "English",
    flag: "",
    completed: true,
    date: "22/01/2019 10:30",
    rate: 9.1,
    categories: {
      de: 1,
      sp: 2,
      uk: 0,
      fr: 1,
      us: 4,
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
```

my fetch in front my fetch in front my fetch in front my fetch in front my fetch in front :

```
 fetchDemo() {
    this.props.demoFetchRequest();
    const { marketId } = this.props.match.params;
    axios.get(`/api/v1/passport-authenticate/market/${marketId}`)
      .then((res) => { return res.data; })
      .then(demo => this.props.demoFetchSuccess(demo))
      .catch(error => this.props.demoFetchError(error));
  }
```

my return my return my return my return my return my return

```
const { demo } = this.props;
```

my render

```
<h5>{demo.title}</h5>
          <p>
            Demo
            {' '}
            {demo.flag}
          </p>
          {demo.map((el) => {
            return (
              <div>
                {Object.keys(el.categories).map((key) => {
                  return (
                    <p>
                      {key}
                      :
                      {el.categories[key]}
                    </p>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            );
          })}
```

can you help me ?

Comment: how are you binding props?

Comment: componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchDemo();
    this.fetchUser();
  }